# Filling form using jQuery when there are no IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to using jQuery and have a widget in a feedback page for clients that ask for name, email, and comments/questions section. I am attempting to auto-fill the email input via passed value through the URL. This part of the code is correct and is represented with `var email`. I am trying to select the input via jQuery but so far have not been successful, as the input tag is heavily embedded within divs, all of which do not have IDs. The input tag also does not have an ID, only a `type`, `name`, and `required pattern`.

Here is what I have so far using jQuery to select the input as well as the code to get the email from the URL:

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
    sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
    sParameterName,
    i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};

var email = getUrlParameter('email');
console.log(email);

// Use jQuery to select the proper input field
var value = $('input[type=email].name').val();
console.log(value);
```

No errors occur whith this code, but I do get back a console log for `value` that says `undefined`. Here is a snapshot of how the tag hierarchy is structured in the widget (please keep in mind I am unable to change the widget code):

[image]

The highlighted element is the one I need to select and change the value of.

Answer (score 1):

Why that `.name` in your selector?

Analyzing your selector, you are selecting an element of type `input` (correct), with type `email` (correct) and class `name`. Incorrect as you input class is empty. In selectors, the dot means class: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

You should remove the `.name` thingy.

Also, if there are more inputs of type email in the list, you should use a selector that is unique for this input. Look for parents ids, unique attributes and such.

You can select an element inside an specific parent simply by prepending the parent selector. I see that you have a parent with id `content` somewhere, then you can do it this way:

```
$("#content input[type='email']")
```

The hashtag means to select by id.

Making the selector more selective (what?), you can select by the input attributes. Just add as much attributes as you want:

```
$("#content input[type='email'][name='email']")
```

If by attributes this input is already unique, you can leave it this way:

```
$("input[type='email'][name='email']")
```

Don't overselect, but also don't underselect. If you add so much elements to you selector, is easily breakable when you change something, but if you add too fewer elements, is easily duplicable when you add content. Just keep it *enough*.

Comment: I think they're trying to filter on the name attribute. `[name="email"]` possibly?

Comment: @AdamMazzarella Yep, sure it goes that way.

Comment: There are no divs with IDs

Comment: @Jodo1992 You have a div with an id up right there. Check the first line of this image: http://i.imgur.com/Y1f9i36.png. Btw, is only a suggestion. You should build up your selector looking at all your site. We only have access to the image you posted.

Comment: This selection method worked, however I am still not able to fill the field with the email from the URL. I tried this line `var value = $('input[type="email"][name="email"]').text(email);` but it seems to have no affect on the widget.

Comment: @Jodo1992 inputs are filled with val. change your `.text(email)` for `.val(email)`. In jQuery, if val has no arguments is to retrieve, if has arguments is for set.

Comment: changing it to `.val(email)` also does nothing. I think it's because the `input` does not have a `value` field, it has a `step value` field.

Comment: @Jodo1992 No. Thats 2 different fields doing nothing one to the another, `step` is one independent field and on the other side `value` is another independent field. By the way, the attributes should not limit setting a value. The only thing I can think of is that there are some code around there setting the value just after you do. Maybe the own widget script. Maybe the widget script cleans the inputs just before showing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling the parent div class of the input. Try this code.

```
$(".Form-field input[type='email']").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't get too specific with your jQuery selectors, you want to give just enough to ensure a unique selection. Give this a shot:

```
var value = $('input[name="email"]');
```

As long as this is is the only input with the name `email` on the page, you will be certain the correct element is grabbed.